# Multithreaded deletion and re-insertion fails with Orient 2.2.29

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm using multiple threads to delete and re-insert different records to the same OrientDB (using different graph instances) but I get a lot of exceptions. I'm having some trouble figuring it out and I haven't found a problem exactly like this on SO. When the delete and re-insert is done sequentially, everything is fine. I've checked to make sure the base graph in the IdGraph objects are different and the transactions I have *appear* okay but now I'm not so sure. FWIW, here are my JVM settings

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xss512K -Xmx2G -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1G -Dstorage.useWAL=false
```

It looks like a record is misread and leads to a `NullPointerException` during a `DELETE VERTEX` command. Here is part of the Exception stack. I am deleting all vertices based on its `n:station` property. The `n:station` property is converted to `n_3astation` so the property key contains valid characters. I then pass `DELETE VERTEX V WHERE n_3astation IN ["station_4681"]` to Orient. There's some delegation on Orient's side to ensure those vertices and their edges are removed. I tried stepping through the code but I get lost in the delegations so I'm unable to track down the problem.

```
WARNING [09:28:11 02-Apr-18 EDT][com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinary] $ANSI{green {db=systemDb}} Error deserializing record with id #9:0 send this data for debugging: 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
SEVERE [09:28:11 02-Apr-18 EDT][com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage] $ANSI{green {db=systemDb}} Exception `59ED03EC` in storage `systemDb`
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.select from `V`  WHERE n_3astation IN ["station_4681"]
        DB name="systemDb"
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3361)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3278)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLQuery.run(OSQLQuery.java:78)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLAsynchQuery.run(OSQLAsynchQuery.java:74)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.query.OQueryAbstract.execute(OQueryAbstract.java:33)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex$2.call(OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex.java:215)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex$2.call(OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex.java:208)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OGraphCommandExecutorSQLFactory.runInTx(OGraphCommandExecutorSQLFactory.java:172)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OGraphCommandExecutorSQLFactory.runInConfiguredTxMode(OGraphCommandExecutorSQLFactory.java:257)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDeleteVertex.java:208)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:70)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3340)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3278)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:69)
        at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphCommand.execute(OrientGraphCommand.java:49)
        at executeQuery(OrientSystemDbConnection.java:502)

Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 58050422
        at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:385)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:425)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.stringFromBytes(ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.java:992)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.readString(ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.java:949)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.deserializeValue(ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.java:408)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.deserializePartial(ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.java:148)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinary.fromStream(ORecordSerializerBinary.java:78)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.deserializeFields(ODocument.java:1854)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.filter.OSQLFilterItemField.getValue(OSQLFilterItemField.java:126)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.filter.OSQLFilterCondition.evaluate(OSQLFilterCondition.java:379)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.filter.OSQLFilterCondition.evaluate(OSQLFilterCondition.java:88)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.filter.OSQLFilter.evaluate(OSQLFilter.java:105)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.evaluateRecord(OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.java:422)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.filter(OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.java:412)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearchRecord(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:609)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.serialIterator(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1642)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.fetchFromTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1589)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearch(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:522)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:485)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:70)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3340)
        ... 27 more
```

### Update

After getting some information from a thread dump, there appears to be a problem with using concurrency when the DB is encrypted. While there isn't a deadlock, I'm able to concurrently update when DB encryption on OrientDB is turned off. Below is part of a stack trace in one of the blocked threads.

Does this mean I can't use concurrency when Orient is encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Orient that was resolved in version 2.2.34

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/8201